# Create a private static field at module level in F#

Tags: f#, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a configured object that can be reused along requests in Azure Functions. The example below is in C#. The idea is to avoid the expensive creation of a customized `DocumentClient` instance for each request. The `client` field is static and is reused in this example taken from the documentation:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

private static DocumentClient client = GetCustomClient();
private static DocumentClient GetCustomClient()
{
    DocumentClient customClient = new DocumentClient(
        new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CosmosDBAccountEndpoint"]), 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CosmosDBAccountKey"],
        new ConnectionPolicy
        {
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
            ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
            // Customize retry options for Throttled requests
            RetryOptions = new RetryOptions()
            {
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 10,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 30
            }
        });

    // Customize PreferredLocations
    customClient.ConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations.Add(LocationNames.CentralUS);
    customClient.ConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations.Add(LocationNames.NorthEurope);

    return customClient;
}

[FunctionName("CosmosDbSample")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "foo/{id}")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    string id,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    Uri documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("ToDoList", "Items", id);
    Document doc = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(documentUri);

    if (doc == null)
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, doc);
}
```

In order to try to simulate with a simpler example, I tried the code below. It works normally:

```
namespace TransactionsAggregate

open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http
open System.Net
open System.Net.Http
open System.Web.Http
open Newtonsoft.Json
open System.Text


module Ping =    


    type Name = {
        First: string
        Last: string
    }

    type Greeting = {
        Greeting: string
    }


    let jsonFormatter = System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter()
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver <- new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()



    [<FunctionName("Ping1")>]
    let run([<HttpTrigger>] req: HttpRequest, log: TraceWriter) =
        async {

        log.Info("Chamando Ping 1")
        let! jsonContent = req.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

        try
            let name = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Name>(jsonContent, jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings)

            let response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            let body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( { Greeting = sprintf "Hello %s %s!" name.First name.Last })
            let content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            response.Content <- content
            return response

        with _ ->
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

In this F# example, we have an Azure Function that runs on V2 version and is written on .NET Core. This is a precompiled function (not an script). It's a class library project. This example just echoes the parameters passed. The `jsonFormatter` is defined and configured at module level and is not marked as static of so. Is there a way to create a static field of something similar so I could cache this jsonFormatter or in the future, a much more expensive object? Also, is there any guarantee that there will be only one instance of this value on the application?

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/cosmos-db

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already achieved your goal. `let` binding in F# module will only be executed once per Azure Functions instance, it's similar to static read-only field in C#.

Azure Functions can run multiple instances (servers) at the same time and over time. Each time a new instance is provisioned, the first execution will be slow and will include your initialization of expensive expressions. The next execution on the same instance will reuse them though, so it will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and also, for your examples in F# :)